# Laravel (windows) storage path

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a problem that I do not know how to resolve. Running Wamp64 on windows.
Image is stored in storage/app/uploads whatever...

However, this code:

```
{{ storage_path('app/').$post->image_path }}
```

gives me error as it cannot find image:

> D:\wamp64\www\lounginator\storage\app/uploads/imagename.jpg

Of course, as slashes are mixed with backslashes. If I upload it to Linux server, all works, of course.

How to overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{{ asset("storage/{$post->image_path}")  }}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your blade you can display in image from local storage like:

`{{ Storage::disk('disk_name')->get('file_name.file_extension')}}`

Comment: Is this gonna work when I upload it to host?